# How to prove this identity (equality)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove following equality:
$$\begin{align*}
&\left(\lambda_1 z_1^2+\lambda_2 z_2^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_1} z_1^2 + \frac{1}{\lambda_2} z_2^2\right)=\\&
=\frac{1}{4}\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}}+\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}} \right )^2(z_1^2+z_2^2)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}}-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}} \right )^2(z_1^2-z_2^2)^2
\end{align*}$$

How we can do it?

Comment: Are you sure that it holds? On the LHS you get a term with $z_1^4$ but there is no such term on the RHS

Comment: @Stefanos [WolframAlpha agrees.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F4%29%28sqrt%28a%2Fb%29%2Bsqrt%28b%2Fa%29%29%5E2%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29-%281%2F4%29%28sqrt%28a%2Fb%29-sqrt%28b%2Fa%29%29%5E2%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%3D%28ax%5E2%2Bby%5E2%29%28%281%2Fa%29x%5E2%2B%281%2Fb%29y%5E2%29)

Comment: wolfram Alpha gives certain values of $x$ and $y$ for which the above identity is true. It does not hold for each $z_1, z_2$, so you cannot prove it. Nevertherless you can solve it.

Comment: It's been proved several times in at least this site that WA saying something can be dead wrong (not to mention the many times people write wrong expressions thus misleading WA). Nevertheless, WA is usually a good lead.

Comment: The post is edit. In addition suppose that $z_1^2+z_2^2=1$.

Comment: If you add $\;z_1^2+z_2^2=1\;$ then this factor in each summand in the right hand is $\;1\;$ ...much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{4}\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}}+\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}} \right )^2(z_1^2+z_2^2)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left (\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}}-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}} \right )^2(z_1^2-z_2^2)^2=$$

$$=\frac14\left[\left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}+2+\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)\left(z_1^4+2z_1^2z_2^2+z_2^4\right)-\left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}-2+\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)\left(z_1^4-2z_1^2z_2^2+z_2^4\right)\right]=$$

$$=\frac1{\rlap{/}4}\left(\rlap /4\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}z_1^2z_2^2+\rlap /4z_1^4+\rlap/4z_2^4+\rlap/4\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}z_1^2z_2^2\right)=\left(\lambda_1 z_1^2+\lambda_2 z_2^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_1} z_1^2 + \frac{1}{\lambda_2} z_2^2\right)\;\;\color{green}{\checkmark\checkmark}$$